# Does $G$ act faithfully on the set $G/H$ of left cosets by left multiplication?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $A$ be a finite index subgroup of a group $G$. Then $G$ acts
>   faithfully on the set $G/A$ of left cosets by left multiplication.

Is this true? I don't see why it wouldn't be, unless this group action is not injective.

Comment: No. The kernel of the action is the intersection of the conjugates of $A$. (Which must be nontrivial if $|G|$ is larger than $|S_{G/A|}| = (|G/A|)!$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, if $A$ is normal for example, the action is faithful if $A$ is trivial.